# How to solve client side validation problem?

Tags: javascript, validation

I am working on a project and need to do some client side validation.
I am doing all validations by calling the onsubmit() method.

The problem that I am facing is that the validation runs just fine when I put into comments a few other statements but not otherwise.

My code:

```
var speak1=document.forms["form"]["speak1"].value
b = checkSpeakLanguages(speak1);
if(b==false){
    return false;
}
```

which calls checkSpeakLanguage works properly.

But the following code works only when the above is put in comments:

```
var m= document.forms["form"]["maritalStatus"].value
b = checkMaritalStatus(m);
if(b==false){
    return false;
}
```

Please help me. Please tell me why both the second part does not work when the other is present.

Comment: Are those 2 bits of code in the same function? If so, what is the value of `b` after calling `checkSpeakLanguages`? If it's `false` then the function will return before it ever gets to the second bit of code.

Comment: The codes are in 2 different functions

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the first `b` returns false, you return before the second part can execute. Combine the functions for your submit handler to something like:

```
function checkSubmit(){
  var cansubmit = true,
      speak1    = document.forms["form"]["speak1"].value,
      m         = document.forms["form"]["maritalStatus"].value;
  if(!checkSpeakLanguages(speak1) || !checkMaritalStatus(m)) {
      cansubmit = false;
  }
  return cansubmit;
}
```